# Camera App disappeared

Tags: camera, hard-reset, front-camera

### My camera app on my Android phone has disappeared.

It all started yesterday.
Everything had been working fine until then, but all of the sudden, my camera app didn't respond anymore (*Can't connect to camera* was the message I was getting).

I got the same message when starting apps that used the camera (e.g. Snapchat).

I went to *Settings->Apps*, and forced-quit every single app and stopped every process; still, nothing.

At that point, I decided to hard reset my phone, and now, there is no camera app at all.

I have tried looking for it in the disabled apps directory in *Settings->Apps*, and still, it is nowhere to find...

I am really frustrated, as I can't use my camera at this point in my mobile phone (neither rear- nor front-camera)...

Is there anything I could do to solve this issue?

**SPECS**:

- Phone: [BQ Aquaris E4.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BQ_Aquaris_E4.5)
- Android: Version 5.0

Comment: Have you tried a factory reset?

Answer (score 0):

Tap on Home icon > Apps and widgets > Settings > Apps > All tab > Scroll down and tap on Camera option > Enable button.

Comment: I have the same issue. What is the home icon?  I cant find apps a widgets either.. with ios, you just slide up from the bottom to get the camera.  Nothing like this on android?